# Is GridLayout supported by proteus? If not then what is an alternative?

Tags: android-gridlayout, proteus

I'm trying to use GridLayout in json like this
`{
  "type": "GridLayout",
  "android": "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android",
  "orientation": "horizontal",
  "layout_width": "match_parent",
  "layout_height": "match_parent",
  "columnCount": "2",
  "rowCount": "2",
  "children": [
    {
      "type": "TextView",
      "layout_width": "wrap_content",
      "layout_height": "wrap_content",
      "layout_columnWeight": "1",
      "layout_marginTop": "8dp",
      "layout_marginLeft": "16dp",
      "textSize": "20dp",
      "textColor": "@android:color/background_dark",
      "text": "244536"
    },
    {
      "type": "TextView",
      "layout_width": "wrap_content",
      "layout_height": "wrap_content",
      "layout_columnWeight": "1",
      "layout_marginTop": "8dp",
      "layout_marginLeft": "16dp",
      "textSize": "20dp",
      "textColor": "@android:color/background_dark",
      "text": "244536"
    }
  ]
}`
I'm getting null when I am preparing a `ProteusView` .

If proteus does not support GridLayout, is there a way to use `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` to get the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proteus currently does NOT have an implementation for `GridLayout`; but you can implement the parser for `GridLayout` yourself and use it. Checkout an example of a custom parser called [`CircleViewParser`](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/proteus/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/flipkart/android/proteus/demo/CircleViewParser.java) and [how to register it](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/proteus/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/flipkart/android/proteus/demo/api/ProteusManager.java).

Alternatively, you can use `LinearLayout` with `layout_weight`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="One" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Two" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Three" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Four" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Proteus currently does have an implementation for GridLayout? Where? Can you provide a link?

Comment: My bad. I meant does NOT have a implementation.